# Programar Servicio solo los días de semana en android

Tags: android, xamarin

Tengo el siguiente código que inicia un servicio todos los días a la hora especificada.
Alguien sabe cómo hacer para que se inicie sólo de lunes a viernes?

```
Calendar startTime = Calendar.GetInstance(Locale.Default);
startTime.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, 10);
startTime.Set(CalendarField.Minute, 00);
startTime.Set(CalendarField.Second, 00);

AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService );
Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(myService));

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetService(context, 0, i, 0);
mgr.SetRepeating(AlarmType.Rtc , startTime.TimeInMillis , 24*60*60*1000 , pi);
```

Comment: Puedes usar el método de @dan_flo10 y configurar 2 días, por ejemplo lunes y miércoles: forday(2); forday(4);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programa 5 alarmas, una por cada día

```
public void alarmas(){
    for(int i = 2; i < 7; i++){//2 es lunes, 7 es sábado
        forday(i);
    }
}

public void forday(int dayOfWeek) {

    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(myService));

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetService(context, 0, i, 0);
    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmType.Rtc, startTime.TimeInMillis, 7*24*60*60*1000 , pi);//7*24*60*60*1000 = cada 7 días
}
```

Comment: Y cómo haría para detener el service exactamente a las 2 horas de que se inició?

Comment: Según yo esa es otra pregunta, pero puedes usar Handler en el servicio

    `private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 1: {
                stopSelf();
            }break;
        }
    }
}

handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 120 * 1000);`